# Relax vs VC-Relax for interstitial incorporation energy

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, geometry-optimization, defects

In order to model an interstitial trapped in a metal lattice, and the associated incorporation energy, which should be used - "relax" or "vc-relax"? I want to understand the lattice expansion from the interstitial, and that tells me vc-relax, while i realize that an interstitial introduction would involve some lattice strain which would suggest relax.

I was using the energy difference $E_{\rm intAinM} = E(M+A)-(E(M)+E(A))$ to calculate interstitial incorporation energy from both, and they are not the same as one would imagine.

I would love you hear some suggestions or insights into this.

Comment: By interstitial incorporation are you considering the interstitial entity to be an impurity?

Comment: Yes. As in a light element (C, H, N or O) in a metal lattice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a large enough supercell such that the effect of vc-relax and relax are negligible. This means that the strain due to the impurity is local.

The following paper provides a comprehensive review on defect calculation in DFT.

https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.86.253

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the reference. I will read it. As a side, may I ask your views about the supercell size used by this study - https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4906047

Comment: I think it should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your time and comment.